# How does BB-8 decelerate?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, droids, bb-8

In The Force Awakens, we see BB-8 stop on each step as he descends a staircase following Rey as she goes to

> Luke Skywalker's light sabre in the basement of Maz Kanata's tavern.

BB-8 literally stops as he lands on each step before starting again to move down to the step below it.

We also see him race and then stop on flat surfaces.

What documentation exists in the Star Wars literature or scripts or interviews of writer's, etc to explain how BB-8 stops himself when he is moving? I imagine that his hardware includes [a gyroscope](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyroscope) and [an accelerometer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerometer) to measure his movement. But how does he stop himself from falling down the stairs when his instruments tell him he is descending? Or stop himself from rolling onward after he reaches a destination?

[image]

Comment: Inertial Dampers...

Comment: No canon info as far as I'm aware

Comment: Clearly someone explained how BB-8 works. This question merely asks for a small piece of the documentation. The explanation of how he slows from a sprint could also explain much of this.

Comment: @CodeMed I suggest you do some Googling. BB-8 in the movie production is a fully functional robotic prop - barring sentient intelligence, it actually works on Earth. So if you're looking for information on its mechanical design, real world technology has the answer you seek. It's not fiction lol

Comment: @CodeMed funny you say that, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112202/how-does-bb-8-climb-stairs?rq=1 with 18 upvotes is literally to the right of your comment on my screen when I read this lol

Comment: @TheGreatJedi I am on the mobile app, which does not show those links, though I clicked your link. I do this at night on my phone with minimal research capabilities, which is why I am more an asker.

Comment: If it can accelerate on the surface, then it can certainly decelerate. The physics are the same, just in the opposite direction. So long as the internal wheels are able to grip the inner surface, then it can counter the rotational momentum. And so long as the external surface can grip the floor, the robot can stop.

Comment: @LeseMajeste Joshua Lee and Matthew Denton built a working BB-8 that was one of a few versions used as props during filming. I wonder if googling their names would reveal technical specs. I'm on my phone so have limited research ability. Halfway through the article in this link they mention the working version http://www.starwars.com/news/droid-dreams-how-neal-scanlan-and-the-star-wars-the-force-awakens-team-brought-bb-8-to-life

Comment: @thegreatjedi: sadly, the answers on http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/112202/how-does-bb-8-climb-stairs don’t actually answer the question of *how*.

Comment: Now all we need is for JJ Abrams to procure working droidekas for the next movie

Comment: @TheGreatJedi They spent $200 million making this movie. Enough to build a droid factory.

Comment: @CodeMed Hard to say. I think a B1 factory will cost as much as it takes to set up a 21st century drone factory, multiplied by the same factor as the difference in cost between a civilian and military jet factory.

Comment: @DVK Maybe a cannon would work! ;)

Comment: @JaneS - now I'm imagining that scene from OfficeSpace... where they destroy office computers and stuff ... With BB-8

Comment: @JaneS I was thinking more that he bounces off the side of the pool table, then hits the 8 ball before landing in the corner pocket.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comments, BB-8 is a real robot invented on planet Earth in the Milky Way galaxy in the present day. With regards to its technical capabilities, a couple fans have done some research and dedicated a whole [website](http://www.howbb8works.com/) to the subject. Since there is little to no CGI used for BB-8, all of its movements in the movie should be fully functional and achievable using real-world tech alone.

In-universe, the main technological advancements that can be possible while having functionally equivalent mechanical performance to what we already witness in reality would include miniaturization, better power systems, smarter programming etc. The generally non-mechanical stuff.

Comment: Thank you and +1. Your link says 2 inner wheels cause BB-8's main ball to roll. There is a counter weight to keep the wheels on the floor side and a ball bearing to press the wheels against the inside of the ball. Another user's comments above give insight into general deceleration. We guess that the reason BB-8 stops at each step is to  avoid uncontrollable acceleration down multiple steps.

Comment: @CodeMed Earlier in the movie's production, I had already heard of the company Sphero mentioned in the website, though I thought it was known that their tech will be used in BB-8 as opposed to mere rumour and speculation. Also, you may want to research more on the patents made for BB-8's tech.

Comment: It’s great that there’s a website explaining BB-8, but Stack Exchange answers ideally include the actual answer to the question in them, rather than just a link.

Comment: +1 for 'is a real robot invented on planet Earth in the Milky Way galaxy in the present day'. How does it work... physics.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite well I chose to defer on a detailed answer because that involves going into mechanical engineering details (which I'm not educated in) and research into a few patents made (I'm not American so idk what I am capable of digging up). Overall, I feel that an answer to this question, if answered completely and self-contained, will require technical knowledge not available to the layman (and an answer length equivalent to a script for a lecture speech). Better to provide some useful starting points to do your own research in this case to the level of detail you seek imo.